# How to convert an ip to string in puppet

Tags: puppet

I am using version 3.8 of puppet and I need to convert an ip address to a string. I tried the String function but I am getting an error.

This is the code I am using:

```
class resolver::params {
  $ip = String($::ipaddress)
  $octs = split($ip, '.')

  file{ '/tmp/teste.txt':
   content => $octs[0]
  }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Syntax error at '('; expected ')' at /etc/puppet/modules/resolver/manifests/params.pp:2 on node  example.intranet.example.br
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

Comment: The `$::ipaddress` fact is *already* a string in Puppet 3 / Facter 2.  The new Puppet type system was rolled out with Puppet 4.  Prior to that, all facts were strings, lists of strings, or hashes with string keys and string values.

Comment: @JohnBollinger pretty much gave the answer, but also type conversions I think require the future parser in 3.8 anyway.

Comment: Also `$octs = split($::ipaddress, '.')` and `$octs[0]` would be better handled as a custom fact.

Comment: So, @JohnBollinger, should I edit the question?

Comment: Also, what could be causing this error?

Comment: I already said what was probably causing the error. Also @JohnBollinger gave you the solution,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [string interpolation](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_data_string.html#interpolation), with the facter variable as the expression to be evaluated, i.e.:

```
$ip = "${::ipaddress}"
```